# File/Calls substitution like LD_PRELOAD

Tags: linux, bash, system-calls, utility

Does there is usual utility which makes a substitution on some calls like *execve* and *open*? Like LD_PRELOAD for calls.

Example:

we have **prog_A** which uses **prog_B**.

some days ago **prog_B** was updated and now **prog_A** failed!(

usual solution is the next:

```
$: mv /usr/bin/prog_b /usr/bin/prog_B.new
$: ln -s /usr/bin/prog_b.old /usr/bin/prog_b
$: ./prog_a                                       # now run
```

but sometimes it's uncomfortably and dirty solution. In some stories the correct way to do so:

```
$: util "execve+open+stat:/usr/bin/prog_b=/usr/bin/prog_b.old" ./prog_a
```

where execve,open & stat are system calls. What is the name of this util?

Comment: why not using `LD_PRELOAD`?

Comment: *util* use it. If i will use LD_P... firstly I have to write func.c with useful for me calls, then compile it and only then write LD_PRELOAD="./wrap_calls.so" ./prog_a. We want to do only the last step in this chain.

Comment: You just need a library that wraps `execve`, `open`, `stat`. Then use `LD_PRELOAD yourlib ./prog_a`. No need for `util`. Or am I missing something? Do you need help on how to create that library?

Comment: You are right. It's not a big deal to do that. But if we have prog_b1, prog_b2, ... prog_bN => we need to write N different *.c(pp) files. It may take some time > 1minute. I thought that it is too common story that there is special util for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just write a special [FILE_PRELOAD](https://github.com/j0k/fp) utility to solve my problem.

```
$: FILE_PRELOAD -C "execve+open+stat:/usr/bin/prog_b:/usr/bin/prog_b.old" ./prog_a
```

it generates c++ code, then compiles it and then LD_PRELOAD the result lib.so file before run ./prog_a.

Using it you can hook the next calls:

1. open,fopen,fopen64
2. opendir,mkdir,rmdir
3. execve
4. unlink,unlinkat
5. stat,lstat,lstat64,_*lxstat,*_lxstat64,stat64
6. _*xstat,*_xstat64,__fxstatat
7. freopen,freopen64

Please, run [docs/tut.sh](https://github.com/j0k/fp/blob/master/docs/tut.sh) firstly (it's a tutorial for FP utility).

Answer (score 0):

The *common* solution is the symlink solution. It isn't dirty. Have a look at `debian` or `Ubuntu` for example. They have `/etc/alternatives` for that purpose.

Here comes an example listing for the `view` command on `Ubuntu`:

```
user@server ls -al /usr/bin/view
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Dez  5  2009 /usr/bin/view -> /etc/alternatives/view
user@server ls -al /etc/alternatives/view
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Dez  5  2009 /etc/alternatives/view -> /usr/bin/vim.basic
```

Comment: Symlinks not dirty, but some time not useful. For example we have prog_a & prog_c which use different versions of prog_b. What will you do?

Comment: I would install proper versions of all programs. But however, I know such situations from real life ;).. Can you tell your reasons why you can't clean up that disaster?

Comment: Some programs created many years ago. They cute but want some old stuff.

Comment: Yes, I have. I didn't remember all examples but last one was the next: gentoo configure ebuilds with the latest automake tool (if there is no description of acceptable version inside ebuild). So i need to downgrade automake package for some packages and then emerge it for new programs.

Comment: Sounds tricky. I'm not a gentoo expert but heard of something like *slots* where different versions can be installed to. If you need alternatives to `LD_PRELOAD` I would mention `chroot` or `$PATH`.

Comment: Understand. $PATH looks like ln -s way. Solution with /etc/alternatives works fine but not with that problem, because there are different progs which used /usr/bin/view, but each of them needs it own version.

Comment: For automake in gentoo it can be solved by $: WANT_AUTOMAKE="1.12" emerge some